# How to resolve cleartext not permitted in aosp

Tags: java, android, https, android-source, cleartext

I know cleartext been disabled by default by android. May I know where exactly I can enable in aosp instead of adding in all packages with network config files?

Where I can permit by adding the below line?

cleartextTrafficPermitted="true

external/okhttp/android/main/java/com/squareup/okttp/Handler

```
 public static OkUrlFactory createHttpOkUrlFactory(Proxy proxy) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        // Explicitly set the timeouts to infinity.
        client.setConnectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        // Set the default (same protocol) redirect behavior. The default can be overridden for
        // each instance using HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects().
        client.setFollowRedirects(HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());

        // Do not permit http -> https and https -> http redirects.
        client.setFollowSslRedirects(false);

        // Permit cleartext traffic only (this is a handler for HTTP, not for HTTPS).
        client.setConnectionSpecs(CLEARTEXT_ONLY);

        // When we do not set the Proxy explicitly OkHttp picks up a ProxySelector using
        // ProxySelector.getDefault().
        if (proxy != null) {
            client.setProxy(proxy);
        }

        // OkHttp requires that we explicitly set the response cache.
        OkUrlFactory okUrlFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);

        // Use the installed NetworkSecurityPolicy to determine which requests are permitted over
        // http.
        OkUrlFactories.setUrlFilter(okUrlFactory, CLEARTEXT_FILTER);

        ResponseCache responseCache = ResponseCache.getDefault();
        if (responseCache != null) {
            AndroidInternal.setResponseCache(okUrlFactory, responseCache);
        }
        return okUrlFactory;
    }

    private static final class CleartextURLFilter implements URLFilter {
        @Override
        public void checkURLPermitted(URL url) throws IOException {
            String host = url.getHost();
            if (!NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance().isCleartextTrafficPermitted(host)) {
                throw new IOException("Cleartext HTTP traffic to " + host + " not permitted");
            }
        }
    }
```

In any apps if I use http, I get error as  Cleartext HTTP traffic to 124.60.5.6 not permitted";

So instead of changing in apps, is it possible to change in aosp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like its enough if you do

```
builder.setCleartextTrafficPermitted(true);
```

in line 189 seems sufficient since you are using older applications which probably doesn't have any network config and only uses default ones.

source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/security/net/config/NetworkSecurityConfig.java#189

---

### Old Answer

I hope you have done your homework on the implications on bypassing a security feature. That being said, the class responsible for the exception is in framework with package `android.security.net.config` and class responsible is `NetworkSecurityConfig`.

As of writing this answer, the static builder class has a property `boolean mCleartextTrafficPermittedSet` which is set to `false` by default. You might have to default it to `true` which makes the method `getEffectiveCleartextTrafficPermitted()` in the `NetworkSecurityConfig` class return `mCleartextTrafficPermitted` which in return returns `DEFAULT_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC_PERMITTED` which is by default set to `true`

The flow would be

`getEffectiveCleartextTrafficPermitted()` returns `mCleartextTrafficPermitted` returns `DEFAULT_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC_PERMITTED` returns `true` by default.

If this is all confusing, call `setCleartextTrafficPermitted(true)` on the builder whenever the builder is created.

The source for the class is available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/security/net/config/NetworkSecurityConfig.java

**Note**: I have not tried this and merely gone through the source and inferred the above. You are welcome to try and correct me if something is wrong.

Edit by updating from @Shadow:

In NetworkSecurityConfig, change the boolean variable from true to false.

```
   //public static final boolean DEFAULT_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC_PERMITTED = true;
    public static final boolean DEFAULT_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC_PERMITTED = false;
```

Also in ManifestConfigSource, comment the below line,

```
  /*boolean usesCleartextTraffic =
                        (mApplicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_USES_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC) != 0
                        && mApplicationInfo.targetSandboxVersion < 2;*/
```

and directly apply as usesCleartextTraffic as true.

```
 boolean usesCleartextTraffic =true;
```

Comment: Thanks vijai this is what I expected. Let me try this and update you soon. Thanks once again. @Vijai

Comment: I used this. builder.setCleartextTrafficPermitted(true); instead of //builder.setCleartextTrafficPermitted(cleartextTrafficPermitted); but still I am getting cleartext http traffic not supported.

Comment: actually I printed log too inside the method getDefaultBuilder but nothing is printing inside that.

Comment: Hmm... probably its here then? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/security/net/config/ManifestConfigSource.java#76

Note: file is ManifestConfigSource.java

Comment: So what actually I need to do? Kindly guide me please @Vijai

Comment: The thing is, when there is no network config, android loads default one. We find it and allow clear text. Revert the old change, go to "ManifestConfigSource.java" in the same location as "NetworkSecurityConfig.java" and `boolean usesCleartextTraffic` to true in line 76.

Comment: Hello Vijai. I have done some changes like in NetworkSecurityConfig, i made this variable from true to false public static final boolean DEFAULT_CLEARTEXT_TRAFFIC_PERMITTED = false; followed by your step. So in this case, i am not getting clear text not supported but instead i get error as failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 8383) after 10000ms. My question is, so now http or https issue resolved or above will reproduce the socket timeout due to this?

Comment: Thanks @Vijai. I have modified your answer and I am accepting and rewarding you bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and add

```xml
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ....
</application>
```

I strongly advise that you create the `network_security_config` to only allow your domain and subdomain. Here is a quick [tutorial](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Comment: If I have 1000 apps, I can't apply everything by creating this network config xml. Instead is it possible to do in framework side? I have full aosp source code for 9. http://androidxref.com/. As android suggested, it has been disabled by default. Exactly where they disabled in aosp?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that if you have a 1000 apps, and they do some update on the framework, you'll have to change it as well ?

Comment: Thing is we need to migrate the apps from 6 to 9. So in this case, instead of changing in every apps, it's better to change in framework. For eg: Background service restriction introduced in 9. In this case, instead of adding it as foreground service in every app, there is a class called as BackgroundExecutionQueue changes made to allow background service not to restrict. Same in this case,  I don't know the work around where exactly they disabled.

Comment: I don't know about changing AOSP but I wouldn't recommend you'll probably hit multiple walls, a third option would be to use a certificate for your website and in this case you won't have to deal with `clearTextTraffic`

Comment: Thing is it's LAN connection. So it communicates with LAN and through LAN connection, it access the controller's internet. So in this case, LAN doesn't have https or http.

Comment: Oh... then yeah searching and modifying the AOSP files is your last resort I think, sorry I couldn't help you much :/